# Entity Framework conflict with same table name from different databases

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 4 with MVC 3 in Visual Studio 2012 (C#).

I am using *database first*; there are two separate databases each with its own namespace and with two separate edmx files. Each database has a table with the same name and fields (but different content). When I added the second table I started to get compile errors.

```
Ambiguity between 'Interface.CodeFormStatus.FormStatusCodeID' 
and 'Interface.CodeFormStatus.FormStatusCodeID'
```

There seem to be some complex workarounds or I could rename one of the tables. Is there not a straightforward solution as this must be a fairly common issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into a situation where I had two databases (one an older version of the other) and I needed to integrate both into a single project. Naturally, almost every name conflicted.

I created two separated edmx files for each database, and put each in its own namespace for clarity. I then edited each entity name to reflect which database it was coming from - (e.g. "Activities", which was in both, became "v13Activities" and "v14Activities").

For operations which were to be mirrored between both databases, I wrote a wrapper that included both contexts. This made my code was much less repetitive, and it had less synchronization issues.

Hope this approach helps someone else - it seems like this is an obscure question, and this answer was one of the top results on Google!

**Update:** In EF 6.1+, there is another solution. You can have "conflicting" names, and separate them with simple namespacing when using the ["Code First From Database" option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.aspx). I would advocate for this solution going forward, as the old XML .edmx style [is going to be phased out starting in EF Core](https://www.techgig.com/skill/visualbasic/blog/EF7-What-Does-Code-First-Only-Really-Mean/576300).

Comment: Your second link is dead.

Comment: @DannyCullen Welp, that sucks. I can't seem to find this article anywhere else, except on one of those blogs that copy/pastes other peoples blogs. I'll update the link to that and reach out to Rowan Miller (The original author of that post) to see if he can get the original back up.

Comment: @CoreyLarson EF 7 was renamed to EF Core.

Comment: @Cameron - Thanks for that - I don't get over to C# land as often as I would like these days, I've fallen out of the loop somewhat on EF.

Comment: This [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35154383/2788458) shows how to do it by setting the Custom Tool Namespace of the .tt file

Comment: You also need to have at least one of the edmx files in a different folder or else the common table .cs files will be overwritten (by the last edmx created)

Answer (score 7):

[This  worked for me.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7259621b-228c-4570-88b2-cced9bce04b4/more-than-one-edmx-having-same-table-mapped?forum=adodotnetentityframework) Just click on the table in the designer (the graphical version not the code) Then in the properties next to the, "Name" attribute you can change the name to something different. This will just change the name within the designer and used more as an alias throughout the application.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have many tables with the same name, then you could edit entity name in designer (your `.edmx` file). 
So, just double-click a name of one of your `CodeFormStatus` entities and make it different (for example, change it to `CodeFormStatusOther`)