# accessing multiple databases from the same project issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, ado.net

EDIT: I came across an old question that has my problem.
[Entity Framework conflict with same table name from different databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599732/entity-framework-conflict-with-same-table-name-from-different-databases)
 one of the solutions is using **Code first for an existing database** and change the namespace. I did use the code first and the generated classes were missing the **LOB** class. please guys, any ideas what to do?

I'm trying to add multiple databases to my project. when I tried to add the second database using the ADO.net model .the generated context class of the first database gave an error.

```
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Lob' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   Manage_account  C:\Users\tmp187115\source\repos\Exit application\Manage_account\Models\Model1.Context.cs    30  Active
```

the problem is in model1, the name of the table is Lob.
the name of the table in phoneScreen model, is LOB 
I would appreciate any guidance .I'm really lost and this project is going to have 6 different databases

the generated context for the phone screen

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Manage_account.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class Phone_ScreeningEntities2 : DbContext
    {
        public Phone_ScreeningEntities2()
            : base("name=Phone_ScreeningEntities2")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Accounts> Accounts { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<LOB> LOB { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Offer_Letter> Offer_Letter { get; set; }
    }

}
```

the connection string in the webconfig

```
    <add name="Phone_ScreeningEntities2" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.phoneScreen.csdl|res://*/Models.phoneScreen.ssdl|res://*/Models.phoneScreen.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\instance;initial catalog=Phone_Screening;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

the generated context for the exit app database

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Manage_account.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class ExitApplication2015Entities : DbContext
    {
        public ExitApplication2015Entities()
            : base("name=ExitApplication2015Entities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<AccountOrOU> AccountOrOUs { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Lob> Lobs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

the connection string in the webconfig

```
    <add name="ExitApplication2015Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\instance;initial catalog=ExitApplication2015;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Exit application lob
[image]

phone screening LOB
[image]

Comment: It would be easier if I could see a snippet of your context.cs. In your context.cs how are you referencing Lob entity?

Comment: Hi @LinkedListT, I edited the post and added a snippet of the context also with the web config.If you wanted me to add anything else , just say so

Comment: Are you connecting to the correct db? It's unable to find the Lob table.

Comment: @LinkedListT I apologize for the late reply. the lob table can't be seen when I connected the second model. I tried to refresh the model. at this moment the second model LOB table can't be seen. I'm in this loop from yesterday and i don't know what to do  ‍♀️

Comment: What version of EF are you using, and can you show us the concrete structure of the table Lob and LOB in the two databases?

Comment: hi, @JackJJun-MSFT I'm using EF 6.4.0  and I edited the post and added the structure of the two tables.

Comment: change the namespace of one of the db entity